# ESRI Popup Maximize button missing

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

Currently working on showing a popup in the map using ESRI ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.15.
But that is missing the Maximize button which was available with ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.35

[image]

Is there any config to be set to show the same.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the new API does not have that capability out of the box. But no worries, you can implement it by adding a custom action to the popup.

See the example I made for you to get an idea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Popup actions | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.18</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.18/"></script>

  <script>
    require(["esri/Map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/views/MapView"], function (
      Map,
      FeatureLayer,
      MapView
    ) {
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "gray-vector"
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-117.08, 34.1],
        zoom: 11
      });

      const toggleFullScreenAction = {
        type: "toggle",
        title: "Full Screen",
        id: "toggle-full-screen",
        className: "esri-icon-maximize"
      };

      view.popup.actions.add(toggleFullScreenAction);


      const template = {
        title: "Trail run",
        content: "{name}"
      };

      featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/TrailRuns/FeatureServer/0",
        outFields: ["*"],
        popupTemplate: template
      });
      map.add(featureLayer);

      function toggleFullScreen() {
        if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
          document.getElementsByClassName('esri-popup__main-container')[0].requestFullscreen()
            .catch(err => {
              alert(`Error attempting to enable full-screen mode: ${err.message} (${err.name})`);
            });
        } else {
          if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
          }
        }
      }

      view.popup.on("trigger-action", function (event) {
        if (event.action.id === "toggle-full-screen") {
          toggleFullScreen();
        }
      });



    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

To run the snippet, copy and save as an html file. The full screen action does not work in the snippet, I guess because it is embedded, not sure though.

Comment: Can you please help me out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630872/display-info-window-on-the-multiple-coordinates-on-the-arcgis-map-in-next-js